# Como criar uma nova configSections em App.config

Tags: .net, vb.net

Estou trabalhando com um aplicação que atualmente utiliza a seção `appSettings` para obter configurações da aplicação através do `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.

Porém gostaria de uma estrutura mais complexa para a minha configuração, algo parecido com isso:

```
<configuration>
  <externalConnections>
    <connection name="Conn1" type="sharepoint">
      <username value="login">
    </connection>
    <connection name="Conn2" type="sap">
      <username value="login">
      <password value="password">
    </connection>
  </externalConnections>
</configuration>
```

Vi algo relacionado com `configSections` porém não sei como criar uma classe para utilizar esse tipo de configuração.

Como posso criar essa classe de configuração? A forma de utilização dessa classe é a partir do `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` também?

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde,

Tive que armazenar a algum tempo algunas informações sobre uma aplicação, configurações de ambiente da mesma, é bem simples

```
    //Instanciando e utilizando o app.conf default da aplicação
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    //adicionado a chave e valor    
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("ConfiguracaoHorario",comboBox_configuracao_horario.Text.ToString());

    //adicionado a chave e valor  
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("IP_Servidor",txt_servidor_banco_dados.Text.ToString());


     //salvando as configurações
     config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);


    //desta forma será armazenado no app.conf assim


    <configuration>
        <appSettings>
            <add key="ConfiguracaoHorario" value="BLABLABLA" />
            <add key="IP_Servidor" value="BLABLABLA" />
        </appSettings>
    </configuration>


    // E para recuperar do arquivo as informações

comboBox_configuracao_horario.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ConfiguracaoHorario");
                txt_servidor_banco_dados.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("IP_Servidor");
```

Esse é a forma mais simples de fazer, no seu caso, nesta estrutura mais completa, sugiro serializar uma classe nesta estrutura, para criar seu xml, de configuração.

Comment: Ok, minha questão é utilizar algo mais elaborado que o `onfigurationManager.AppSettings`. Como faço isso?

Comment: Este tuto tem o que presica: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.configuration.configurationelement(v=vs.110).aspx